# How to fix "Attempted to remove more RCTLinkingManager listeners than added" in react-native

Tags: ios, reactjs, react-native, console, deep-linking

When i start react-native run-ios, then a screen of simulator is shown like followed screenshot picture...

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N5Lrk.png)

It says that "Attempted to remove more RCTLinkingManager listeners than added"

But I don't know how to fix this.

I think the problem was appeared when I tried to link url with ios.
(I followed this instruction https://reactnative.dev/docs/linking#enabling-deep-links)

Here is my AppDelegate.m code:

```
#import "AppDelegate.h"

#if RCT_DEV
#import <React/RCTDevLoadingView.h>
#endif

#import <React/RCTBridge.h>
#import <React/RCTBundleURLProvider.h>
#import <React/RCTRootView.h>

#ifdef FB_SONARKIT_ENABLED
#import <FlipperKit/FlipperClient.h>
#import <FlipperKitLayoutPlugin/FlipperKitLayoutPlugin.h>
#import <FlipperKitUserDefaultsPlugin/FKUserDefaultsPlugin.h>
#import <FlipperKitNetworkPlugin/FlipperKitNetworkPlugin.h>
#import <SKIOSNetworkPlugin/SKIOSNetworkAdapter.h>
#import <FlipperKitReactPlugin/FlipperKitReactPlugin.h>
#import <React/RCTLinkingManager.h>

static void InitializeFlipper(UIApplication *application) {
  FlipperClient *client = [FlipperClient sharedClient];
  SKDescriptorMapper *layoutDescriptorMapper = [[SKDescriptorMapper alloc] initWithDefaults];
  [client addPlugin:[[FlipperKitLayoutPlugin alloc] initWithRootNode:application withDescriptorMapper:layoutDescriptorMapper]];
  [client addPlugin:[[FKUserDefaultsPlugin alloc] initWithSuiteName:nil]];
  [client addPlugin:[FlipperKitReactPlugin new]];
  [client addPlugin:[[FlipperKitNetworkPlugin alloc] initWithNetworkAdapter:[SKIOSNetworkAdapter new]]];
  [client start];
}
#endif

@implementation AppDelegate

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application
   openURL:(NSURL *)url
   options:(NSDictionary<UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey,id> *)options
{
  return [RCTLinkingManager application:application openURL:url options:options];
}

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application continueUserActivity:(nonnull NSUserActivity *)userActivity
 restorationHandler:(nonnull void (^)(NSArray<id<UIUserActivityRestoring>> * _Nullable))restorationHandler
{
 return [RCTLinkingManager application:application
                  continueUserActivity:userActivity
                    restorationHandler:restorationHandler];
}

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
#ifdef FB_SONARKIT_ENABLED
  InitializeFlipper(application);
#endif

  RCTBridge *bridge = [[RCTBridge alloc] initWithDelegate:self launchOptions:launchOptions];
  #if RCT_DEV
  [bridge moduleForClass:[RCTDevLoadingView class]];
  #endif
  RCTRootView *rootView = [[RCTRootView alloc] initWithBridge:bridge
                                                   moduleName:@"app2"
                                            initialProperties:nil];
  

  if (@available(iOS 13.0, *)) {
      rootView.backgroundColor = [UIColor systemBackgroundColor];
  } else {
      rootView.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
  }

  self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[UIScreen mainScreen].bounds];
  UIViewController *rootViewController = [UIViewController new];
  rootViewController.view = rootView;
  self.window.rootViewController = rootViewController;
  [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
  return YES;
}

- (NSURL *)sourceURLForBridge:(RCTBridge *)bridge
{
#if DEBUG
  return [[RCTBundleURLProvider sharedSettings] jsBundleURLForBundleRoot:@"index" fallbackResource:nil];
#else
  return [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"main" withExtension:@"jsbundle"];
#endif
}

@end
```

Please I would be very appreciated for your help. Thank you

Comment: Are you using aws-amplify ?

Comment: Yes!!  I'm using aws amplify and react-native cli

Comment: they are working on fix for it please follow this https://github.com/aws-amplify/amplify-js/issues/8902

Comment: Thank you for your help Fadi Abo Msalam I am very appreciate for your comment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this unstable release in the interim, until they release a stable one next week.

"aws-amplify": "4.3.3-unstable.4"

according to @elorzafe https://issueexplorer.com/issue/aws-amplify/amplify-js/8902

Comment: Thanks for your help!!!!

Comment: I just solved the problem with your answer, thanks again!!!